# Foreign Key Reference to IdentityUser Shows NULL Values (EF6/ASP.NET MVC 5)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-6

I am trying to figure out why my model table's UserId column which references the primary key, "Id" of my AspNetUsers table (IdentityUser class in IdentityModel) is showing only NULL values when I '***Create()***' an entry.

Here is the code for my two Create(), ActionResult methods in my controller class:

```
[Authorize]
    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        ViewBag.UserId = new SelectList(db.Users, "Id", "Fullname");
        return View();
    }

    // POST: Expenses/Create

    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    [Authorize]
    public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "ID,Category,Description,GrossAmount,TaxAmount,NetAmount,Mileage,MileageRate,DateSubmitted,ExpenseDate,UserId")] Expense expense)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            expense.UserId = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name;
            db.Expenses.Add(expense);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        ViewBag.UserId = new SelectList(db.Users, "Id", "Fullname", expense.UserId);
        return View(expense);
    }
```

Here is the code for my Create view:

```
    @{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";

    DateTime today = DateTime.Today;
    string formattedDate = today.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
}

<h2>Create</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>Expense</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.UserId, htmlAttributes: new { @Value = user, @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.UserId, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.UserId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.DateSubmitted, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.DateSubmitted, new { htmlAttributes = new { @Value = formattedDate, @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DateSubmitted, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ExpenseDate, htmlAttributes: new { @Value = @formattedDate, @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ExpenseDate, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ExpenseDate, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Category, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Category, new SelectList(
                  new List<String>{
                       "Meals & Entertainment",
                       "Home Office",
                       "Travel",
                       "Phone",
                       "Auto - Mileage",
                       "Auto - Gas",
                       "Auto - Lease",
                       "Association Dues",
                       "Insurance Premium",
                       "Capital Assets",
                       "Trade Show & Promo",
                       "Pan Experience",
                       "Other"
                    }), new { @class = "form-control" })

                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Category, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Description, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Description, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Description, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Mileage, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Mileage, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Mileage, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.MileageRate, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.MileageRate, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.MileageRate, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.GrossAmount, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.GrossAmount, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.GrossAmount, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.TaxAmount, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.TaxAmount, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.TaxAmount, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.NetAmount, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.NetAmount, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.NetAmount, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>


        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>

@section scripts {

    <script type="text/javascript">
        var province = 'bc';
        var grossAmount = document.getElementById('GrossAmount').value;

        $(function () {

            $('#ExpenseDate').datetimepicker({

                defaultDate: '@formattedDate',

                format: 'L',

                showClose: true,

                showClear: true,

                toolbarPlacement: 'top'

            });

        });

        $('#DateSubmitted').prop('readonly', true);
        $('#Mileage').prop('disabled', true);
        $('#MileageRate').prop('disabled', true);

        $(function ()
        {
            $('#Category').on('change',function()
            {
                if ($(this).val() == 'Auto - Mileage')
                {
                    $('#Mileage').prop('disabled', false);
                    $('#MileageRate').prop('disabled', false);
                }
                else
                {
                    $('#Mileage').prop('disabled', true);
                    $('#MileageRate').prop('disabled', true);
                }

            }

            )
        })


    </script>
}
```

If you would like to take a look at my model classes, you can go this post:

- [How To Restrict User Entries Only to that Sepcific User in EF 6/ASP.NET MVC 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32364763/how-to-restrict-user-entries-only-to-that-sepcific-user-in-ef-6-asp-net-mvc-5/32365055#32365055)

---

**UPDATE:**

Thanks to Steve Greene for putting me on the right track and for helping me to update my **Create()** method to this:

```
public ActionResult Create()
    {
        ViewBag.UserId = new SelectList(db.Users, "Id", "Fullname");
        return View();
    }

    // POST: Expenses/Create

    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    [Authorize]
    public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "ExpenseId,Category,Description,GrossAmount,TaxAmount,NetAmount,Mileage,MileageRate,DateSubmitted,ExpenseDate,UserId")] Expense expense)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            expense.UserId = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name;
            db.Expenses.Add(expense);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        ViewBag.UserId = new SelectList(db.Users, "Id", "Fullname", expense.UserId);

        foreach (ModelState modelState in ViewData.ModelState.Values)
        {
            foreach (ModelError error in modelState.Errors)
            {
                Response.Write(error);
            }
        }
        Response.End();
        return View(expense);

    }
```

I don't get any major errors now, however, now **ModelState.IsValid** is returning False and the data I enter into Create.cshtml isn't being submitted.

I added a piece of code in the Create() method to catch the **ModelState.Errors** and it prints the error: **System.Web.Mvc.ModelError**.

I've also set a breakpoint before Create() and when I check the value of UserId, I get "null."

---

**LAST UPDATE:**

I've added a field for UserId to the Create.cshtml view and now I get the error: **The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_dbo.Expenses_dbo.AspNetUsers_ApplicationUser_Id". The conflict occurred in database "PacificPetExpenses", table "dbo.AspNetUsers", column 'Id'.**

To fix this, I modified something in my controller (please see my answer below).

Thank you.

Comment: So does your expense object have a UserId at the top of the POST? May need to see the create view code for the user drop down. Make sure it is binding back to your UserId field.

Comment: @SteveGreene I just posted my Create view code.

Comment: I don't see a UserId in your view. Are you intending to present a drop down list of users to choose or do you want to use a static user id such as the logged in user? I see you build a list in the GET action but never display it.

Comment: @SteveGreene I definitely want a static user id (the logged in user) to be posted to the UserId column of my Expense table. Also, I'm not sure exactly what you mean when you say you "don't see a UserId in my view." I didn't think I had to display any of that information in my view.

Comment: You don't have to display it, but when your expense model get's posted back it will be null. So you could either add a hidden field or set the vaue in the post. See my edit below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside of the **Create()** method inside of my controller, I had the line:

```
expense.UserId = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name;
```

I set up a break point and as breakpoint was on the line, it showed the correct UserId; however, after the line had executed, it showed the user's email address.

To fix this I tried changing the line above to:

```
expense.UserId = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.GetUserId();
```

and expenses were both being submitted with no errors and displaying in the view where it was supposed to show the list of expenses submitted by the user!

Answer (score 1):

If you are not using the UserId in the view, just set it before you add:

```
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        expense.UserId = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name;  // or whatever
        db.Expenses.Add(expense);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

Another common pattern is to add a hidden field for the UserId:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.UserId)  <-- now it will post back
    ...
```

If you want to have a drop down list of users, do this:

```
[Authorize]
public ActionResult Create()
{
    ViewBag.UserList = new SelectList(db.Users, "Id", "Fullname");
    return View();
}
```

Then in your view add a drop down list of users:

```
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.UserId, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.UserId, Model.UserList, new { @class = "form-control" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.UserId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, however, now I'm getting an error that says : **The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_dbo.Expenses_dbo.AspNetUsers_ApplicationUser_Id". The conflict occurred in database "PacificPetExpenses", table "dbo.AspNetUsers", column 'Id'.**

Comment: Does the user id exist in the database? Check the value of UserId right before SaveChanges() and make sure that Id is in the table AspNetUsers.

Comment: When I set a breakpoint before the Create() method, UserId is null and since "ModelState" isn't valid, neither the Create(), nor SaveChanges() methods get executed. I added a piece of code to catch all the ModelState.Errors (please see my update in the questions above) and it catches the error of System.Web.Mvc.ModelError.